# Webrick server not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed ruby 2.0.0 and ran

```
 gem install rails
```

to install gems. It installed all gems properly. For my existing rails app, I ran "bundle install" command and then typed this command in terminal:

```
 rails s
```

to start webrick server.

But server failed to start and i am getting this error:

```
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/lib/rails_generator/options.rb:32:in `default_options': undefined method `write_inheritable_attribute' for Rails::Generator::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Can anybody tell why this error is comming? And how to get rails server up and running? Thanks.

Comment: check your rails version with `rails -v`

Comment: @rmagnum2002 your are right. It is Rails 2.3.14
. What to do to make it 4. I install 4 but dont know why it is taking 2.3.14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to install rails 4.0:

```
gem install rails --version 4.0.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/6/25/Rails-4-0-final/

**Note!**, for better ruby versions management you would want to use **RVM**:

http://rvm.io/rvm/install

then install **ruby**:

http://rvm.io/rubies/installing

after installing rvm and ruby you can switch between **ruby versions** with:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

or other ruby version you have installed, to see what **ruby versions** you have, run:

```
rvm list
```

after switching yo your desired ruby version, you can install **rails**:

```
gem install rails --version 4.0.0
```

or another rails version that you need.

A nice **tutorial** here:

http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html

Comment: Hey, I ran command gem install rails --version 4.0.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc. But still output of rails -v is Rails 2.3.14
My ruby -v is ruby 2.0.0p247. I am using rvm.

Comment: i did 'rvm rubygems current' and 'gem install rails' initially then checked rails -v, which is 2.3.14. Now i ran \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails. But still rails -v is Rails 2.3.14 .

Comment: again, run `rvm list`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33706/discussion-between-user2206724-and-rmagnum2002)

Comment: hey, thr? SOrry for disturbing but m facing problem with ruby. Can u help, please?

Comment: I am out of town and will be back in 2 days. So I can't help you much by then. Leave a error log on pastie.org and at least I'll look at it.

Comment: Things not working at all :-( Trying a lot but no success yet. Here is link of log : http://pastie.org/8161770. Can u help?

Comment: Never had this issue and can't find any post related to it, the only thing I can suggest here is to remove all your rubies with `rvm uninstall 1.9.3` or what ruby versions you have and install them back after this, `bundle install` to install gems.

Comment: not sure really if the above suggestion will help you.. why don't you try running `bundle install – -deployment` without deployment? a simple bundle install.

Comment: move to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33706/discussion-between-user2206724-and-rmagnum2002

Comment: hey just saw msg. U thr?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33898/discussion-between-user2206724-and-rmagnum2002)

Comment: hey, thr? I am facing trouble in migration. Can u help? Please

Answer (score 0):

I got this error from rails runner when it used the default Rails 2.3.11 version provided by my service provider instead of the intended Rails 4.0.1 version. However, prefixing the command line with 'bundle exec' solved the problem. This works for me:

bundle exec rails runner 'puts "Hello!"'